# For what value c is $f(x) = \frac{x^2+5x-14}{x^3-x^2-x-2}$ at 2 continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Im pretty new to continuinity and it seems for me the function can as easily be repaired with $c = 2$ so that $g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2+5x-14}{x^3-x^2-x-2}, & x > 2\\
0, & x = 2 \\ \frac{x^2+5x-14}{x^3-x^2-x-2}, & x < 2
\end{cases} $

, because $f(2) = \frac{0}{0}$, which is a gap in the function and the function. But plotting the function proves it otherwise, because the value is ~1,5. So I'd have to take the limes from the left and right to this point, $left-\lim\limits_{n \to 2} \frac{x^2+5x-14}{x^3-x^2-x-2} = \frac{2^2+5\cdot2-14}{2^3-2^2-2-2} = \frac{0}{0}$... Help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Since the limit is indeterminate, you could use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of plugging $2$ directly into the expression, first factor the numerator and denominator as
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 5x - 14}{x^3 - x^2 - x - 2} = \frac{(x + 7)(x - 2)}{(x - 2)(x^2 + x + 1)} = \frac{x + 7}{x^2 + x + 1}.$$
Then substituting $x = 2$ tells you that
$$\lim_{x \to 2}f(x) = \frac{2 + 7}{2^2 + 2 + 1} = \frac{9}{7}.$$
So the function is continuous if $g(c) = 9/7$.

Comment: How do you for yourself look at $x^2+5x-14$ and come up that it must be $(x+7)(x-2) $?I have a difficult time seeing such transformations

Comment: $(x + a)(x + b) = x^2 + (a + b)x + ab$, so to factor $x^2 + 5x - 14$ you just need to find two numbers $a,b$ with $a + b = 5$ and $ab = -14$

Comment: Wow didn't expect an answer that fast at this time, thanks a lot!